# Not able to enroll to Apple Developer Program, Getting error - (Please ensure your device and iCloud account meet our system requirements)

Tags: ios, icloud

I am trying to Renew to Apple developer program. But got the error.

I checked many tutorials but issue not solved still getting error. App So i downloaded Developer app and logged in using my Apple developer account. But when i click on "Renew" button i am getting this error

> Please ensure your device and iCloud account meet our system requirements

On MAC Apple Developer App, i am trying to renew the subscription but got this error

Comment: can you check it, there are some solutions on there:https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/720277 or https://appletoolbox.com/icloud-account-problems-heres-how-to-solve-them/

Comment: Try with iOS App with Latest OS. I successfully renew developer program from iOS.
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/apple-developer/id640199958?platform=iphone

Comment: Did you solve this? Facing the same issue and suspecting it might be because I've installed Ventura on a 2012 macbook using opencore.

Comment: you need to update OS and developer app to latest version

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the phone number country code on your `icloud` matches the country that you are in!
This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the Developer app to the latest version solved my problem.